# How to create 1D array structure using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, data-structures, structure

I'm trying to replicate the attached image.    However, I'm not really sure what type of command or environment to use.

[image]

Comment: Hi @R Mustang and welcome to TeX.SE. Are you looking for something specific? It could be a table, a TikZ figure, a matrix. Is the "Figure 4 ..." just the legend of the figure?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use TikZ, `tabularray` is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                column{1-Y}={20pt, c, colsep=3pt, font={\bfseries}},
                column{Z}={l, font={\bfseries}},
                row{2-Z}={20pt, m},
                hline{2,Z}={1-Y}{1.5pt,solid},
                hline{3} ={1}{1-Y}{1.5pt,solid},
                hline{3} ={2}{1-Y}{1.5pt,solid},
                rulesep=10pt,
                abovesep=4.5pt,
                belowsep=1.5pt,
                vline{1-Y}={2,3}{1.5pt, solid}
                }
            0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&\\
            0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&B\\
            0&2&5&6&6&8&8&9&10&10&count\\
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{For $i=1$}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a TikZ solution. You can add additional data to the `\foreach` list if you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
\foreach \b/\c[count=\n, evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n-1)] in {0/0,0/2,1/5,0/6,0/6,0/8,0/8,0/9,0/10,0/10}{
    \node[box,label=above:\m] at (\n,1.5){\b};
    \node[box] at (\n,0){\c};
    \xdef\lastn{\n} 
}
\node[right] at (.5+\lastn,1.5){B};
\node[right] at (.5+\lastn,0){count};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```